# Structuring Query to return Subquery results

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.e_id, dbo.tbl_Lifitng_Details.det_con, dbo.tbl_contracts.clientID, dbo.tbl_contracts.contractNumber, dbo.tbl_contracts.fin_approved, 
                         dbo.tbl_work_locations.work_location, dbo.tbl_contracts.wLocationID
    FROM                 dbo.tbl_Lifitng_Details RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tbl_work_locations INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tbl_contracts ON dbo.tbl_work_locations.work_id = dbo.tbl_contracts.wLocationID ON dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id = dbo.tbl_contracts.conNo AND 
                         dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.lifting_loc = dbo.tbl_contracts.conLoc ON dbo.tbl_Lifitng_Details.det_con = dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id AND 
                         dbo.tbl_Lifitng_Details.det_loc = dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.lifting_loc
    WHERE tbl_lifting_gear.con_id = @con AND tbl_lifting_gear.lifting_loc = @loc

        (
        SELECT TOP 1 e_id AS defects
        FROM tbl_Lifting_Gear
        WHERE tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id = @con AND tbl_Lifting_Gear.e_defects = 'Y' AND lifting_loc = @loc) 

       (
       SELECT TOP 1 e_id AS addInfo
       FROM tbl_Lifting_Gear
       WHERE tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id = @con  AND tbl_Lifting_Gear.e_add = 'Y' AND lifting_loc = @loc) 

       (
       SELECT TOP 1 e_id AS mark
       FROM tbl_Lifting_Gear
       WHERE tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id = @con AND lifting_loc = @loc  AND tbl_Lifting_Gear.inspected = 'N') 

       (
       SELECT TOP 1 e_id AS thorough
       FROM tbl_Lifting_Gear
       WHERE lifting_through IS NOT NULL AND lifting_through <> 0 AND con_id = @con AND lifting_loc = @loc)
```

How do I structure this query so the results for the sub queries are returned as part of the main query? (as defects, addInfo, mark and thorough). Think I have the AS statements in the wrong place, but when I try to put them outside the () for each subquery it returns a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the subqueries to your select list:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.e_id, dbo.tbl_Lifitng_Details.det_con, dbo.tbl_contracts.clientID, dbo.tbl_contracts.contractNumber, dbo.tbl_contracts.fin_approved, 
                         dbo.tbl_work_locations.work_location, dbo.tbl_contracts.wLocationID,
                         (
        SELECT TOP 1 e_id AS defects
        FROM tbl_Lifting_Gear
        WHERE tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id = @con AND tbl_Lifting_Gear.e_defects = 'Y' AND lifting_loc = @loc),
        (
       SELECT TOP 1 e_id AS addInfo
       FROM tbl_Lifting_Gear
       WHERE tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id = @con  AND tbl_Lifting_Gear.e_add = 'Y' AND lifting_loc = @loc),
       (
       SELECT TOP 1 e_id AS mark
       FROM tbl_Lifting_Gear
       WHERE tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id = @con AND lifting_loc = @loc  AND tbl_Lifting_Gear.inspected = 'N'),
       (
       SELECT TOP 1 e_id AS thorough
       FROM tbl_Lifting_Gear
       WHERE lifting_through IS NOT NULL AND lifting_through <> 0 AND con_id = @con AND lifting_loc = @loc) 
    FROM                 dbo.tbl_Lifitng_Details RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tbl_work_locations INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tbl_contracts ON dbo.tbl_work_locations.work_id = dbo.tbl_contracts.wLocationID ON dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id = dbo.tbl_contracts.conNo AND 
                         dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.lifting_loc = dbo.tbl_contracts.conLoc ON dbo.tbl_Lifitng_Details.det_con = dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.con_id AND 
                         dbo.tbl_Lifitng_Details.det_loc = dbo.tbl_Lifting_Gear.lifting_loc
    WHERE tbl_lifting_gear.con_id = @con AND tbl_lifting_gear.lifting_loc = @loc
```

Comment: Ok...feel a bit monday-stupid now :) Many thanks, I should have sussed that, cheers!